# Creating readonly nested objects in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm new to .net and looking for advise on how best to create readonly object structures. These structures are laid out at compile time and will not change at all. My object looks like this:

```
Public Structure CatPair
    Public code, name As String
End Structure

Public Structure Category
    Public code, name As String
    Public subcategories() As EpfPair
End Structure

Public ReadOnly categories() As Category = {
    New Category With {.code = "Code1", .name = "cat title 1", .subcategories = Nothing
    },
    New Category With {.code = "Code2", .name = "cat title 2", .subcategories = Nothing
    },
    New Category With {.code = "Code3", .name = "cat title 3", .subcategories = Nothing
    },
    New Category With {.code = "Code4", .name = "cat title 4", .subcategories = {
            New CatPair With {.code = "subC1", .name = "subcat title 1"},
            New CatPair With {.code = "subc2", .name = "subcat title 2"},
            New CatPair With {.code = "subc3", .name = "subcat title 3"}
        }
    },
    New Category With {.code = "Code5", .name = "Cat title 5", .subcategories = Nothing
    }
}
```

So the object is actually a nested table of constants, where some have subcategories and some don't. My goal here is to:

1. Ensure that everything is readonly, and
2. Implement it in a way (if possible) so that my ASP.net pages that don't use this code are not incurring any significant overhead of initialising the object every time a page is loaded. I have declared the object in a module in the App_Code folder so I'm not sure how the compiler processes pages that don't touch the object.

Comment: The term you should be using is `immutable`.

Comment: If this is ASP.NET the tag it as such.  It has been a while since I did ASP.NET so I don't remember the exact term but create you categories in app.startup (not session.startup).  Then all sessions and all pages just reference that same single categories.

Answer (score 1):

Code you provided will not achieve your goals. To make objects immutable you will need at least to make object's properties readonly (no setter), just passing everything in constructor parameters instead.